# UDP listener only receives first incoming message - how to keep receiving additional messages?

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, udpclient

I'm trying to build a simple Windows Forms app in VB.net (.net Framework 2.0 in order to support Windows XP) which allows multiple client PCs to send short text strings as UDP messages to a listening "server".

The "server" part must listen asynchronously and display the received text from each client as it arrives.

My code can't use the newer ReceiveAsync() function because it must support XP and thus must be built on .net Framework 2.0, which doesn't support these Async functions, so I'm using the BeginReceive() function and passing a callback.

It works perfectly for the **first** incoming UDP message, but the problem is that no additional messages are received.  Even if I send the same message twice, nothing is output after receiving the first incoming message.  It's as if the listener ignores anything after the first message, or as if it's hung in an incorrect state. Is there some sort of "reset" procedure that must be performed on the UDP listener after each incoming message in order that it will listen for further incoming data?  (Note: no exceptions are raised)

Here's my listener code:

```
Private Sub btnListen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnListen.Click
        Dim state As New UdpState
        listener = New UdpClient(CInt(txtListenPort.Text))  ' Create UDP client on specified port (all interfaces)

        'Async receive data:
        Dim ip As System.Net.IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList(0)

        state.udpClient = listener
        state.ipEndPoint = New Net.IPEndPoint(ip, CInt(txtListenPort.Text))
        Dim callback As AsyncCallback
        callback = AddressOf rx
        listener.BeginReceive(callback, state)
        lblListenStatus.Text = "Listening..."

    End Sub

Shared Sub rx(result As IAsyncResult)
        Dim r As UdpState = result.AsyncState
        Dim endpt As System.Net.IPEndPoint = r.ipEndPoint
        Dim client As UdpClient = r.udpClient
        Dim bytes() As Byte
        bytes = client.EndReceive(result, endpt)
        Dim s As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        Debug.Print("Received string = " & s)

    End Sub

Private Class UdpState
        Public ipEndPoint As System.Net.IPEndPoint
        Public udpClient As System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
    End Class
```

And here's the code I'm using to send data to this socket endpoint:

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        Dim send As New UdpClient
        Dim s As String = txtSendMessage.Text
        Dim b_len As Integer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(s)
        Dim b() As Byte
        ReDim b(b_len)
        b = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)  'Convert text to bytes.
        send.Send(b, b_len, txtSendIP.Text, CInt(txtSendPort.Text)) 'Blocking SEND.
        send.Close()

    End Sub
```

Note that I'm testing sending from localhost to itself - not even sending over the network.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: How many times does `BeginReceive` get called?  That would be the maximum number of times you can receive anything.  If you want to receive multiple times, you need to call that method multiple times.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So I am supposed to call BeginReceive() again after every EndReceive()? It's like a "one-shot" async function?

Comment: Yes, you need to call it in your `rx` callback after `EndReceive`.

Comment: Possibly, declare your AsyncCallback as a Field: `private shared myAsyncCallback as AsyncCallback  = nothing`. Then *new* it before you create the UdpClient object: myAsyncCallback = New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback). So, don't declare your callback in a `Button.Click` event. After `Debug.Print(...)` (as in your code or whatever comes next), call `listener.BeginReceive(myAsyncCallback, state)` again.

Comment: This way you can use the same static (`Shared`) delegate, otherwise you'll have to declare a new one, since you dont' have the callback reference anymore in your `Shared Sub rx()`